# How does a TB3 robot get the coordinates of others?

Tags: ros2, ros-kinetic, turtlebot3, multi-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are three TB3(A,B,C) robots.  Each robot has an independent coordinate system.　The movement of A needs to be changed according to the location of B and C.　How does A get the position of B and C (expressed in the coordinate system of A robot)？
I know that the UAV's solution is to use some indoor location system.　Does TB3 also need a positioning system? 　If necessary, 　what indoor positioning products can achieve high precision positioning function?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303939/how-does-a-tb3-robot-get-the-coordinates-of-others?/) by [jiangzhiwen](https://answers.ros.org/users/37635/jiangzhiwen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-09-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not something that is done trivially with ROS.
You need to fulfill additional requirements, that are more or less tricky:

1. same coordinate system: You need to somehow reference the robots in the same coordinate system. This could be the same map they localize in, a world frame of which you now the location of in the different maps or an indoor position system as it is done for UAVs.
2. communication between robots: this can be done using custom protocols or using one of the multi-robot approaches, e.g. [multimaster_fkie](http://wiki.ros.org/multimaster_fkie).
3. navigation: obviously, your navigation packages need to handle those robots correctly as well. There have been some approaches, but I no of no specific open source one that is used more often.

For indoor positioning, the best are probably motion capture tools like OptiTrack or ViCon. But know that they will be WAY more expensive than your three TBs....

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-09-24**:
as @allenh1 mentioned in #q303940 this question seems to be about ros2. My answer relates to ros...